# Указанная служба не установлена

Tags: windows

Службу устанавливал батником

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe C:\Srvc_MOF_Slime_Total_Production\Srvc_MOF_Slime_Total_Production\bin\Debug\Srvc_MOF_Slime_Total_Production.exe
pause
```

Пытаюсь батником ее перезапустить:

```
net stop "ServiceMOFSlimeTotal";
sc start "ServiceMOFSlimeTotal";
pause
```

Остановить он её может, а вот запустить уже нет. Как решить?

net start не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net stop "ServiceMOFSlimeTotal"
net start "ServiceMOFSlimeTotal"
pause
```

Без точек с запятой.

Answer (score 1):

У вас три команды слиты воедино, а нужно писать с новой строки:

останов службы

```
net stop "ServiceMOFSlimeTotal"
```

запуск службы

```
net start "ServiceMOFSlimeTotal"
```

пауза

```
pause
```